# Websphere JTA - Last resource Configuration

Tags: java, websphere, jta, gemfire

In a Websphere application we have a requirement for JTA transactions with JMS +  Gemfire. Based on product recommendations, we're trying to configure Gemfire as last-resource. There is not enough support/example in the documentation

http://gemfire82.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/transactions/JTA_transactions_with_GemFire.html#concept_csy_vfb_wk

JTA - Websphere UOW
Resources - JMS, Gemfire (8.2.1)

Can someone publish a sample websphere-ra.xml?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a corresponding `websphere-ra.xml` for the `weblogic-ra.xml` mentioned on the link you've provided (i.e. seems like there are no vendor specific resource adapter deployment descriptor extensions for WebSphere). What Weblogic extension does is just define a connection factory for the deployed RAR. You may do this (define a connection factory for your resource adapter) using admin console or wsadmin at WebSphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no websphere-specific resource deployment descriptors for WebSphere Application Server.  Last agent optimization can be configured for a server or for an application.  To configure it for a server, in full profile, you enable 'Accept Heuristic Hazard' in the transaction service settings.  Example:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_contranserv.html

If you choose instead the application level, you need to use the websphere-specific extensions to the deployment descriptor for applications.  The setting is called 'Last participant support'.  Example:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/lao/tasks/tla_cfap2.html

When correctly configured, the server will allow a single one-phase resource to enlist in a global transaction, and will treat it as the last agent.  If more than one one-phase resource is enlisted, you will get an exception.  In this specific case, you would need to make sure that the JMS resources are XA-capable so that they will not try to be the last agent.